# Configuring Nutch to write to Apache Kudu

Tags: hadoop, nosql, web-crawler, nutch, apache-kudu

I am trying to configure Apache Nutch to write to Apache Kudu, but I cannot find anywhere informations about how to do it. I know I can write to Cassandra and HBase, but there is nothing about Kudu.

The Hadoop distribution that I am using is CDH 5.16.1

How do I configure Apache Nucth to write to Apache Kudu?

Comment: Nutch was written before Kudu, and Cloudera doesn't support Nutch, so I'm not sure there is a direct integration here without you adding it to Nutch on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Kudu is not support out of the box by Apache Nutch. Writing an integration should not be very complicated since Nutch has a pluggable output/indexing system.

You could write an [indexer plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexWriters) by implementing the [`IndexWriter` interface](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexWriter.java). We always welcome new contributions & contributors.